# Zoom & Pan entire website

Tags: zooming, pan

I was looking for a way to zoom in and out on a website and then move around.

I tried zoomooz, which works for the zoom but I cannot move around the website.
Zynga Scroller looks promising, but can't get it running.

Ideas?

Comment: I would say this is off-topic as a general computing question. However, just hold CTRL while using your mouse-wheel to zoom in and out, then just use your arrow keys to navigate.

Comment: Hey, I know this :) Would like a "software" solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CSS?

```
.zoom0 { zoom:1 }
.zoom1 { zoom:1.25 }
.zoom2 { zoom:1.5 }
.zoom3 { zoom:1.75 }
.zoom4 { zoom:2 }
```

Assuming you have a button to toggle them:

```
<button type="button">Zoom</button>
```

And some JS:

```
(function(){
  var zoom = 0;
  $("button").on("click", function(e){
     $("body").removeClass("zoom0 zoom1 zoom2 zoom3 zoom4");
     if (zoom++ >= 4) zoom = 0;
     $("body").addClass("zoom" + zoom);
  });
}());
```